# WSo2 API Manager 1.6.0 - Where is hazelcast clustering?

Tags: configuration, wso2, config

While attempting to build a cluster for APIM the only documentation I've been led to is:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Creating+a+Cluster

Which references tribes instead of hazelcast.

I've found some other blogs with hazelcast information but nothing from WSo2.
Does anyone know of actual WSo2 doc that defines their needed settings for clustering under Hazelcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLustering for the new version of WSO2 API Manager is her

http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Overview

Answer (score 1):

Found it under carbon 4.2.0 documentation:
http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29918203